# Is there a theoretical basis for any popular income- or wealth-distribution model?

Tags: inequality, theory

When modelling income or wealth, we probably want a continuous distribution with a lower bound; statisticians have named [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals,_usually_[0,%E2%88%9E)), but [Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) and [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) distributions have been among the most historically popular. Many studies have tested how well these fit the data, and (when they seemed to) estimated the parameters. But is there a theoretical basis for either of these, or for any other model? I found [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.4410.pdf) motivation for a Gamma distribution, but I suspect it's *far* from being mainstream in economics.